# Why does the google calculator give $\tan 90^{\circ} = 1.6331779e^{+16}$?

Tags: trigonometry, floating-point

I typed in $\tan 90^{\circ}$ in Google and it gave $1.6331779\mathrm{E}16$. How did it come to this answer? Limits? Some magic?

Comment: Compute $90\cdot \pi/180$ using floating point types. You don't get exactly $\pi/2$.

Comment: It is an incredibly big number. I think it is some internal rounding issue so it gives such a big number, rather than an error message. Have you tried the same question with radians? Just curious

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The closest IEEE-754 `double` value to $\pi/2$ is $1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375$. The cosine of that, on standard x86_64 hardware evaluates to $6.123233995736766 \times 10^{-17}$. The reciprocal of that is $1.633123935319537 \times 10^{16}$.

Comment: ah more a tecnical answer! :D

Comment: Thi is the result of dividing by a "zero" double.

Comment: @wok No, dividing by zero will get you an infinity, if the numerator isn't zero, and a `NaN` if it is zero, in IEEE floating point. What we have here is that a value ($\pi/2$) is approximated by the closest representable value. Then - depending on the implementation - the cosine of that approximation is computed as accurately as possible [or very close to as accurately as possible, a _relative_ error of $2^{-50}$ would be about the end of tolerance], which results in a value of about the same magnitude ($\approx2^{-52}$) and opposite sign as the used approximation to $\pi/2$.

Comment: The computed sine of the approximation is $1$, division yields the reciprocal of the cosine; or the tangent _of the approximation to_ $\pi/2$ is directly approximated by a rational function, as closely as possible, resulting in a value slightly different from the reciprocal of the cosine, but close. $\tan (\pi/2-\varepsilon) = \cos\varepsilon/\sin\varepsilon \approx (1-\varepsilon^2/2)(\varepsilon - \varepsilon^3/6) = 1/\varepsilon-\varepsilon/2 + O(\varepsilon^2)$.

Comment: Interesting how it's still not quite the same answer. I wonder what this tells us about the architecture they use.

Comment: @deed02392 More probably than the architecture, it's the implementation of $\tan$.

Comment: The reciprocal of cosine is secant, not tangent.  Of course, for angles very close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the difference is negligible.

Comment: It's funny that the number is now `1.63312394e+16`, did some Google employee see your answer and observe their search engine answer was off? :)

Answer (score 61):

As Daniel Fischer said, it's because of rounding errors within [IEEE floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) math, which is extremely widespread in computers and programming languages. Since he's explained why it's precisely *that* number, I'll take a stab at the more general answer.

## The example

```
((1.0 - 0.9) - 0.1) = -2.7755575615628914*10^-17
```

This is obviously mathematically wrong, but it occurs because the computer (A) does not have infinite precision and (B) does not store numbers in base-10. The key that `0.9` and `0.1` cannot be cannot be exactly represented, just like how "one third" cannot be exactly represented in decimal.

The problem doesn't show *immediately* (`print(0.9)` comes out fine) because the computer is smart enough to round small deviations when it converts them to decimals, but the "relative distance" between `0` and `-2.8*10^-17` is a bit too much to hide.

## Bits and bytes

Assuming we're looking at a 32-bit `float`, `-0.9` is stored as:

```
Section         Bits                       Translation
+/1 sign bit    1                          Is negative
exponent:       01111110                   -1 (126 above a -127 offset)
mantissa        11001100110011001100110    0.79999995231628426710886
```

Notice how the mantissa contains a repeating `1100`? pattern? It's almost exactly like storing `1/3` as `0.3333333333` in decimal. In both cases you can't store it precisely without running out of space.

Anyway, when you put the parts of that representation together, you get:

```
(-1) * 2^(-1) * (1+ 0.79999995231628426710886)
```

Or roughly `-0.8999999761581421`. This disconnect between the decimal representation (which is nice) and the binary representation (which is ugly... er, incomplete) is the first domino in a potential cascade of subtle rounding error.

Comment: IMO, the binary representation in your example is actually quite pretty: it's a truncation of $0.8 = 8/10 = 12/15 = 1100_2/1111_2 = 0.110011001100\dots_2$

Comment: I tried this in node.js, and it works! > ((1.0 - 0.9) - 0.1)
>> -2.7755575615628914e-17

Comment: Yes, Javascript actually has only has `double` numbers, even when you write integers, which makes it easy to demonstrate the problem with JSFiddle and similar tools. Note: As long as your integers are within +/- 2^53 they can still be exactly represented. This is because a 64-bit `double` has 53 bits for the sign and mantissa.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen : Good point, this is analogous to the problem of expressing 1/3 in decimal, where you are forced to approximate it as 0.33333 etc. In this case, the repeating-ness occurs in binary storage.

Comment: On my machine the error shows up from `1-0.7-0.3 = 5.55111e-17` and evaluates "correctly" for `1-0.6-0.4` and `1-0.5-0.5`.

Comment: Wow, `((1. - 0.9) - 0.1)` even produces `-2.77556*10^-17` in the all-mighty *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 16):

This is apparently the consequnce of some rounding error. The number given would be the correct result for $\tan(89.9999999999999964917593431035141398\ldots^\circ)$.

Answer (score 6):

Because it seems that Google Calculator works internally

- in radians instead of degrees
- with floating-point arithmetic instead of [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation)

The use of radians means that GC is using an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians.  The nearest representable `double` value is $1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375$.  I shall denote this approximated value by $\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \approx 6.123233995736766 \times 10^{-17} $ (calculated by using a higher-precision value of $\pi$).

Recall that $\tan (\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon) = \cot \epsilon = \frac{1}{\tan \epsilon} $.  On my machine, this evaluates to $1.633123935319537 \times 10^{16}$.  (The  [small-angle approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) of $\cot \epsilon \approx \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ happens to give the same answer.)  This is close to what Google Calculator returned, but differs by 33 ppm.